# How to detect if android app is open from a notification sent with PushSharp?

Tags: android, push-notification, pushsharp

So I'm using PushSharp to send notification in c# to my android app :

```
      var push = new PushBroker();
      push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(androidKey) { });
      push.QueueNotification(
                new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(registrationId)
                    .WithJson("{\"alert\":\"" + PushMessageFormater.FormatMessage(ncRuleResult) + "\",\"badge\":7,\"sound\":\"sound.caf\"}"));
```

Everything works fine, notification are correctly sent.

Now, all I want to do is to detect from my MainActivity if app is open when the final user tap in a received notification.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    registrationGetter = new RegistrationGetter(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent() ;

   // How to check from here if the app is actually open further to a push tap.
}
```

All I found in SO is that I need to put some extra variable on the Intent, but unfornately, I can't find a way to specify the Intent from PushSharp.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you receiving push notifications in your device ??

Comment: yes I'm receiving push notifications in my device.

Comment: you have to check from a background service/ broadcast receiver  for checking if the app is in background or running.. if you invoke a activity while receiving notification in receiver makes your app to come foreground..

Comment: ty @user1992200, but my question was not very clear. I've added that part : "Now, all I want to do is to detect from my MainActivity if app is open when the final user tap in a received notification."

Comment: checking if the app is in foreground  from main activity is pointless .. while tapping the notification you have to invoke a service to check if app is background or not..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76425/discussion-between-user1992200-and-pablo-honey).

Answer (score 0):

change pending intent to invoke service while tapping on a notification

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 579, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

[refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/checking-if-an-android-application-is-running-in-the-background)  to check whether the app is in foreground or not.. you have to check this from your service invoked after tapping the received notification..